# AudioWorklet and GainNode to control volume

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I'm trying to volume control using AudioWorklet and GainNode but it is not working, without AudioWorket it was working well.

Here is the implementation

```
this.audioContext = new AudioContext({
      latencyHint: 'interactive',
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate,
      sinkId: audioinput || "default"
    });
    this.audioContext.onstatechange = () => {
      if (this.audioContext) {
        this.state = this.audioContext.state;
      } else {
        this.state = AudioState.CLOSED;
      }
    };
    this.audioBuffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(1, this.audioSize, this.sampleRate);
    this.audioSource = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.audioSource.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
    this.audioGain = this.audioContext.createGain();
    this.audioSource.connect(this.audioGain);
    this.audioSource.loop = true;
    this.audioContext.audioWorklet
    .addModule('workers/speaker-worklet-processor.js')
    .then(() => {
      this.speakerWorklet = new AudioWorkletNode(
        this.audioContext,
        'speaker-worklet-processor',
        {
          channelCount: 1,
          processorOptions: {
            bufferSize: 160,
            channelCount: 1,
          },
        },
      );
      this.audioGain.connect(this.speakerWorklet).connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Receiver ", err);
    });
```

Here is how I'm setting the new volume.

```
public changeVolume(value: number): void {
  const volume = Number(value) / 100;
  if (this.state !== AudioState.CLOSED) {
    this.audioGain.gain.value = volume;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just added

```
this.audioGain.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
```

and connected directly with worklet node

```
 this.speakerWorklet.connect(this.audioGain);
```

Here is the full code

```
  this.audioContext = new AudioContext({
      latencyHint: 'interactive',
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate,
      sinkId: audioinput || "default"
    });
    this.audioContext.onstatechange = () => {
      if (this.audioContext) {
        this.state = this.audioContext.state;
      } else {
        this.state = AudioState.CLOSED;
      }
    };
    this.audioBuffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(1, this.audioSize, this.sampleRate);
    this.audioSource = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.audioSource.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
    this.audioGain = this.audioContext.createGain();
    this.audioGain.gain.minVal = 0.0;
    this.audioGain.gain.maxVal = 1.0;
    this.audioSource.connect(this.audioGain);
    this.audioSource.loop = true;
    this.audioGain.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    this.audioContext.audioWorklet
    .addModule('workers/speaker-worklet-processor.js')
    .then(() => {
      this.speakerWorklet = new AudioWorkletNode(
        this.audioContext,
        'speaker-worklet-processor',
        {
          channelCount: 1,
          processorOptions: {
            bufferSize: 160,
            channelCount: 1,
          },
        },
      );
      this.speakerWorklet.connect(this.audioGain);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Receiver ", err);
    });
```